# F# Quotations and Code Comment Expressions

Tags: f#, metaprogramming

It turns out that it is really hard to google the word comment.

Is is possible to represent "comment" expressions in quotations abstract syntax tree?

```
<@ //this gets ignored by the compiler and don't inject the quotation
@>
```

If not, can you suggest a workaround to represent the comments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ganesh points out, the `Expr` type has no way of representing comments - the F# quotations really represent just the AST of the expression, rather than full information about the source code (although you can get a file name & a location of a quoted expression).

To somehow embed comments in quotations, you'd need to come up with a way of embedding comments as valid F# code that means something - so you could e.g. define a dummy function `comment` and do something like this:

```
let comment (s:string) = ()

let sample =
  <@ comment "this is not ignored"
     1 + ( comment "this is also not ignored"
           4 ) @>
```

Then you could write an active pattern that looks for an expression of the form `comment "..."; <expr>` and extract the string and the following `<expr>`:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let (|Comment|_|) = function
  | Patterns.Sequential(DerivedPatterns.SpecificCall <@@ comment @@> (None, [], [Patterns.Value(comment, _)]), body) ->
      Some(unbox<string> comment, body)
  | _ -> None
```

Using the pattern, we can now write an (incomplete) pattern matching that succeeds when the top-level expression is some commented `body` expression:

```
match sample with
| Comment(comment, body) -> 
    printfn "// %s\n%A" comment body
```

This is not a very nice way of doing it, but I guess it is as good as it can get if you want to embed some annotations in a hand-written quotation code.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Expr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370577.aspx) type that quotations return doesn't contain any way to represent a comment, so this is very unlikely to be possible.